# How do you create a new user in Stream Chat?

Tags: python, authentication, jwt, chat

I'm currently trying to create a new user in stream chat. I have the following code:

```
server_client = StreamChat(api_key=API_KEY, api_secret=API_SECRET)
    for user in USERS:
        # token = server_client.create_token(str(user["id"]))
        server_client.update_user(user)
```

However, I'm currently getting this error:

```
stream_chat.base.exceptions.StreamAPIException: StreamChat error code 43: UpdateUsers failed with error: "JWTAuth error: signature is not valid. Make sure the token is created using the secret for API key
```

Would anyone know how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

`update_user` has been deprecated in favour of `upsert_user`.

Docs here: https://getstream.io/chat/docs/python/?language=python#syncing-users

It seems like you may be using the wrong secret+key combination. You can also verify the users that have been created on the Stream Dashboard in the **Explorer** tab.